# How to process firestore query as i am getting snapshot result as FIRQuerySnapshot`

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift4, querying

I am facing problem while processing firestore query as my code is here

```
let wallpaperRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("wallpaper").order(by: "noOfDownloads", descending: true)

wallpaperRef.getDocuments(completion: { (snap, error) in
    if error == nil {
        print(snap)
    }

})
```

now the output of this query is this

```
Optional(<FIRQuerySnapshot: 0x600000070640>)
Optional(<FIRQuerySnapshot: 0x600000070640>)
Optional(<FIRQuerySnapshot: 0x6000000705c0>)
```

i want to take this querysnap and get data whatever is init to readable form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a query against a collection, the result you get is a `QuerySnapshot` that contains (possibly) multiple documents. To get each document, you need to loop over the results. From the [Firebase documentation on reading multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection):

```
db.collection("cities").whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
}
```

So your code is jut missing the loop from that `else` block. Something like:

```
wallpaperRef.getDocuments(completion: { (snap, error) in
    if error == nil {
        print(snap)
    } else {
        for document in snap!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
        }
    }
})
```